# Conflicts between CSS Menu and Image as Links

Tags: css, image, hyperlink

There is logo on the top (image as link) and other images as links. These links are not working in FF and safari. The problem is with css/ul/li based navigation menu. If I remove the menu html code, images as links are working fine. The css based navigation menu is based on this code:

```
/* Navigation Menu */
#nav a, #nav a:hover, #nav a:focus {...}
#nav {...}
#nav ul {...}
#nav .menu .level1-li {...}
#nav .menu a {...}
#nav .menu a.level1-a {...}
#nav .menu .sub {...}
#nav .menu .sub a {...}
#nav .menu a:hover {...}
```

I am not much familiar with CSS and this is the example I have downloaded from the web. It seems "a" is doing something wrong here.

Prashant

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML markup and the CSS properties within the braces?

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav a, #nav a:hover, #nav a:focus {direction:ltr; outline:0;}
#nav {background:#252525; background:url(../images/tabs_0.gif) repeat-x left top;height:30px; font:normal 12px/30px arial, verdana, sans-serif; width:800px; margin:0 auto;border-bottom-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-color:#525151;}
#nav ul {margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; display:inline-block;}
#nav .menu .level1-li {float:left; display:inline; width:160px; margin-top:-32000px;}
#nav .menu a {background:transparent;display:block; font-weight:bold; width:160px; text-decoration:none; text-align:center; color:#fff;}
#nav .menu a.level1-a {position:relative; float:left; display:inline; margin-right:-159px; margin-top:32000px;}
#nav .menu .sub {background:#F6C739;float:left; margin-top:-30px; padding-top:30px; margin-bottom:-32000px;}
#nav .menu .sub a {background:#4a4a4a; font-weight: normal; font-size: 9pt;text-align:left; position:relative; margin-right:-1px;text-indent:10px;}
#nav .menu a:hover {background:#F6C739;margin-right:0px; color:#000000;}
```